# How to Use leaflet-distortableimage in a TypeScript Project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, leaflet

I am trying to integrate the leaflet-distortableimage package into my React with TypeScript project but have run into a type error I can't seem to resolve. I am using the package alongside Leaflet, and here is the relevant code snippet:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-distortableimage';

const map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
const img = 'link-to-your-image-file.jpg';

L.distortableImageOverlay(img, {
  corners: [
    L.latLng(51.52,-0.14),
    L.latLng(51.52, -0.10),
    L.latLng(51.50, -0.10),
    L.latLng(51.50, -0.14)
  ]
}).addTo(map);
```

When I attempt to compile this code, TypeScript returns the following error: `Property 'distortableImageOverlay' does not exist on type 'typeof import("path/to/@types/leaflet/index")'.`

I've looked into the @types/leaflet package, but it seems like it doesn't include type definitions for leaflet-distortableimage.

Has anyone successfully used leaflet-distortableimage with TypeScript and can guide me on how to resolve this issue? I am looking for either a way to suppress this specific TypeScript error or to correctly define the type.

Any help or pointers to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

i have tried declaring module, and define types but havent had any success.